# Google Place API issue

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google place API to get Hospitals near a location.

This ( 24.4758,54.3747 )Lat long **gives only two hospitals**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=24.4758,54.3747&radius=50000&types=hospital&sensor=false&key=YourAPIkey

And I searched **Hospitals near Al Sharqi St - Abu Dhabi** on Google maps shows more then ten hospitals.

Please suggest what else need to include in place api request to get all hospitals.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All places are categorized under the type `establishment` until Google has enough metadata about a place to categorize it under supported place types like `restaurant`, `bar`, `hospital` etc.

A workaround would be to pass the place category type as a `keyword` instead of type. The `keyword` parameter is matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=24.4758,54.3747&radius=50000&keyword=hospital&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Please do not post your API Key as it is linked to your developer account. I would advise resetting it in you [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) asap.